# plot coefficient point estimate with standard errors for factors

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, boxplot

Suppose I have a dataframe

```
rn = c('disease1', 'disease1', 'disease2', 'disease2') 
coef = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4) 
std = c(0.003, 0.003, 0.002, 0.0004) 
group = c(1,0,1,0)
df = data.frame(rn, coef, std)
```

What I want to do is get a plot where I would get the coefficient and the standard error plotted for each given `rn` but do this by factors( group=1 or group=0)

For now my code is

```
library('ggplot2')
plot_heterogenous <- ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(rn), y=coef)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color='firebrick') +
  geom_point(aes(fill=as.factor(group))) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=wave1_coef-wave1_std, ymax=wave1_coef+wave1_std), width=0, color="steelblue4") + 
  coord_flip() + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-0.2, 0.2)) +
  theme_bw()+
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank())+
  labs(y= "Treatment effect (standard deviations)", x="")
```

but it does not display it like a grouped boxplot the way i would want. Instead it just graphs the point one next to the other with respect to the group whereas i would want something like this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHLkS.png)

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you simply want to have the points within each `rn` shifted depending on their group? In that case what you want is to use a position "dodge":

```
df = data.frame(rn = factor(c('disease1', 'disease1', 'disease2', 'disease2') )
                coef = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4) 
                std = c(0.003, 0.003, 0.002, 0.0004) 
                group = factor(c(1,0,1,0)))  

ggplot(df, aes(x=rn, y=coef)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=group), position = position_dodge(.9)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color='firebrick')
```

[image: graph using position dodge]